# Problem: control Session timeout

Tags: asp.net, membership

My session renews every 20 minutes. I've set timeout to 300 minutes but still it renews probably because Application Pool recycles.

I am storing UserId which is Guid in Session which returns null. Problem is when I use Membership using

```
Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```

it works fine. But obviously it makes a database call. How can I prevent this problem from happening? Why does Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey succeeds whereas Session doesn't?

Comment: please post your web.config ; and look at my answer

Answer (score 3):

In order to complete Jan's and Neil's answers, you should look at your *web.config* and set **both timeouts** (*sessionState* and *authentication*)

```
<sessionState timeout="300"/>
```

**Sessionstate timeout** specifies the number of minutes a session can be idle before it is abandoned. The default is 20.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"  timeout="300" />
</authentication>
```

**Forms timeout** is used to specify a limited lifetime for the forms authentication session. The default value is 30 minutes. If a persistent forms authentication cookie is issued, the timeout attribute is also used to set the lifetime of the persistent cookie.

Comment: I don't think this will solve the issue. I had both timeout as 2880 which is just too big! I sign in a user using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true); Is there any else to be done also?

Answer (score 1):

Your session may still be alive (if you set it to 300 minutes) but the ASP.NET membership could be expiring?

Have you increased the authentication timeout too?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login/" timeout="180"/>
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing authentication and session. These are two completely different concepts.
`GetUser()` return the currently authenticated user form your MemberShipProvider.

Session and authentication have different timeouts - so its valid that your session times out but the user is still authenticated.